# Merge rows with same id and time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the format

```
id  time  a  b
01    01  1  0
01    01  0  1
01    01  0  0
01    02  0  0
01    02  1  0
01    03  1  0
01    03  0  1
```

So now, the output should be

```
id  time  a  b
01    01  1  1
01    02  1  0
01    03  1  1
```

Here, I am basically merging all rows with same `id` and `time` such the the values in other rows are max of all the values for that `id` and `time`.

I am currently doing

```
df = df.groupby(['id','time']).max()
```

However, this is taking a lot of time (>10 mins) as the number of rows and columns is large. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do the same thing!

Comment: Unlikely. How many rows is 'large'?

Comment: The number of rows is ~1.2m and the number of columns is ~50

Comment: You want the max of all 50 columns?

Comment: Then I do not believe there is an easy solution without upgrading your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take advantage of `multiprocessing` if your hardware allows you to work on several cores simultaneously, and parallelize the calculation of the `max` by group:

Using a random sample with 25 columns and `['id', 'time']` as `MultiIndex`::

```
cols = {'id': np.random.randint(1, 11, 10000), 'time': np.random.randint(1, 11, 10000)}
cols.update({k: np.random.random(size=10000) for k in range(25)})
df = pd.DataFrame(cols).set_index(['id', 'time'])

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 10000 entries, (4, 9) to (3, 4)
Data columns (total 25 columns):
0     10000 non-null float64
1     10000 non-null float64
2     10000 non-null float64
3     10000 non-null float64
4     10000 non-null float64
....
20    10000 non-null float64
21    10000 non-null float64
22    10000 non-null float64
23    10000 non-null float64
24    10000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(25)
memory usage: 2.0+ MB
```

Next, grouping by `['id', 'time']` levels and capturing group ids:

```
grps = df.groupby(level=['id', 'time'])
index = [grp[0] for grp in grps]
```

Resulting in 100 groups:

```
'# Groups: ', len([grp[0] for grp in grps])

# Groups:  100
```

Finally, setting up a `Pool` with 8 workers (# cores), and running the 100 groups through the pool via `functools.partial` to pass along the `axis=0` parameter:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    imap_res = pool.imap(partial(np.amax, axis=0), [grp[1] for grp in grps])
```

Concatenating the result back into `DataFrame` via `list comprehension`:

```
    result = pd.concat([pd.Series(res) for res in imap_res], axis=1).T.sort_index(axis=1)
    result.index = index

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 100 entries, (1, 1) to (10, 10)
Data columns (total 25 columns):
0     100 non-null float64
1     100 non-null float64
2     100 non-null float64
3     100 non-null float64
4     100 non-null float64
....
20    100 non-null float64
21    100 non-null float64
22    100 non-null float64
23    100 non-null float64
24    100 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(25)
memory usage: 20.3+ KB
```